# Complie LESS in Yii

Tags: css, yii, less

I'm working on an web application based on Yii where user can control the color scheme of the UI. For that I'm currently using Embed CSS with dynamic values taken from user inputs in a layout file.

eg: `.btn-user { background: <?=$btnUser?> }`

Now I have decided to use LESS instead of CSS and using LESS variables to set the color codes. At the moment I'm using Grunt to compile my codes locally. I need to compile some of my LESS variables in server-side inside the layout file like I'm doing with embed CSS above.

eg:

```
<style type="text/less">
   @btn-user: <?=$btnUser?>;
</style>
```

How can I compile these embed type variables?

Thanks

Comment: You want Yii to print the variables values? before you compile it?
or are you looking for something to work on the fly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to declare LESS variables in the HTML <head>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824828/is-it-possible-to-declare-less-variables-in-the-html-head)

Comment: If I understand it right, no, it's not possible. I'm not aware of any tool that can take Less code from an arbitrary file, compile it and put the result back (or use in another Less code). So you need to re-think this somehow in a different way.